# Javascript functions not being added to the object prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have several other instances of adding prototypes to javascript classes in my code that work just fine, and I'm unable to work out exactly why the part I've just written refuses to work.
The part in question is:

```
var opt = new Settings;

function Settings() {
    this.initjQuerySelectors();
    this.sorted_columns_url = this.getSortedColumnsUrl();
}

Settings.prototype.initjQuerySelectors = function() {
    this.data_store_selector = $('.data_store.display');
};

Settings.prototype.getSortedColumnsUrl = function() {
    return this.data_store_selector.val();
};
```

and it produces the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Settings> has no method 'initjQuerySelectors'
```

when I attempted to catch the error, it stated that there was also no method for `getSortedColumnsUrl();` either.

Looking at the code with chrome development tools, it shows that there is indeed nothing in the Settings prototype that I've added, the problem is I can't work out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because you ordered your code incorrectly,

Try to define the prototype first, and instantiate the opt object only after that.

```
Settings.prototype.initjQuerySelectors = function() {
    this.data_store_selector = $('.data_store.display');
};

Settings.prototype.getSortedColumnsUrl = function() {
    return this.data_store_selector.val();
};

function Settings() {
    this.initjQuerySelectors();
    this.sorted_columns_url = this.getSortedColumnsUrl();
}

var opt = new Settings;
```

**EDIT:**

Define the function before extending it's prototype for full cross browser support. (thanks to @Turnerj for fix)

Comment: This works, thank you. To be honest, I hadn't considered it as at least once in my code I initiate an object before defining it, and then define the prototypes after that - and it all works fine. Any idea what might be causing the inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: @sjmarshy: it's consistent. You can only invoke a function after definition. And keep in mind that named functions hoisted

Comment: I tried it in Firefox and it doesn't work. You need to declare `Settings` before setting the prototype. http://jsfiddle.net/YJdks/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/YJdks/1/

Comment: @Turnerj it's your `try` block that's breaking it, function hoisting will work if you remove it. more info : http://statichtml.com/2011/spidermonkey-function-hoisting.html

Comment: That only means that @Turnerj is right, and his fix covers more cases.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realise that would take affect. The `try` block was only there to show the error for people who couldn't be bothered opening the console. Edit: Also reading through that article @DavidMcMullin, I am surprised the `try` blocks it, I can understand the `if` blocking it though. Cheers for the heads-up.

Comment: @Rodik quite right and IMO abusing function hoisting hurts readability, but now we all understand *exactly* what was happening =)